# What is the best place to store configuration files in a war file so that they can be imported easily using Spring

Tags: spring

I am using Spring framework in my project. I have to store all the configuration files in the war file as per my requirement. The main configuration file `applicationContext.xml` will be loaded from web.xml. I have to import rest of the configuration files in the `applicationContext.xml` file. What is the best place to store rest of the config files  so that they can be imported easily in the `applicationContext.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For Dynamic application it will good to put your spring xml file in

[image]

2. For standalone project it will good to put your spring xml file in src package not in other package.